How to see "date modified" of a featureclass in ArcGIS Pro
In ArcCatalog it was possible to see the date modified of a featureclass inside a file geodatabase. Is it possible to do this in ArcGIS Pro Catalog View as well? And how?


You can

Show detailed Pop-ups
Or: Swith to View


